# How to find a utf8 code from html document?

Tags: html, vb.net, utf-8

I'm currently scraping info from a website which uses icon fonts to identify information. When I find the element that contains the icon I get the "" character as expected. I want to identify the utf8 code of the character and as such be able to identify which symbol was used.

I'm looking to do something along these lines:

```vb
For Each HTMLElement in HTMLDocument.getElementsbyClassName("icon-class")
  utf8code = HTMLElement.innerText
  If utf8code = U+00AE Then
    'do things
  End If
Next
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `If` block and set a break point on this line: `utf8code = HTMLElement.innerText`? _The debugger should tell you what values you're working with,_ and from there you can start to write the `If` or `Select` block.

Comment: in the debugger the only information I have been able to identify is the innerText and that once again just shows up as the "unknown character" glyph. if I check the html source code I also see an unknown character glyph. its only when a document is correctly coded in utf8 that anything else shows up, and that supposes that you are using a font face that has something at the address it is referencing.


if I could just get the code for the character in question, but everything I have seen has tried to represent the character using the default characteristics for displaying text.

Comment: this site does what I'm asking::
https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php :: when I paste the characters into it, it gives me the code.
I just seem to be hitting a brick wall on how to do the same within my program

Comment: You misunderstand how that "unknown character" glyph works. The raw bytes for the original character are _still there_.What you see on the screen is what that current does when it can't find a glyph that matches the actual data, but that doesn't mean the raw data changed. You can even copy/paste that data into your source code.

Comment: I do understand that, the question is how do I decode that byte data from the string to interpret it in a meaningful manner. right now I am passing the innertext to a utf8encoding variable using get bytes. this creates a byte array with four indexes. When I check the len of the innertext I get two, despite it showing in debug as "". First guess is that the extra char is probably a null char to terminate a string or something. So I'm guessing that I need to work out how the 4 four indexed byte values relate to the utf code and then be able to reverse engineer the utf code from that

Comment: There might not be an extra character. Utf-8 glyphs are sometimes represented with two characters.

Comment: ok so I'm getting closer: right now I have this, array(243, 178, 129, 139)
I need to work out how to meaningfully relate that to some utf code so I can identify which character is being used and execute the next instruction accordingly

Comment: @SimonGreen if `array(243, 178, 129, 139)` represents a UTF-8 byte sequence (`0xF3 0xB2 0x81 0x8B` in hex) then decoded it is Unicode codepoint [`U+F204B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f204b/index.htm) (the same number displayed in ``), which is a [PRIVATE USE codepoint](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UF0000.pdf), which means it can be used however the HTML wants. There is no standard Unicode character defined for that codepoint, but the HTML may be using a custom font that defines its own glyph for that codepoint. So just scraping the HTML has no meaning without context

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is perfect, you worked out the code correctly(but you already knew that). However, I'm not sure how I can get to the code U+F204B from the byte array in visual basic. I'm not even sure of how to it manually to be honest. I understand a bit about hex but not enough to be sure of how to do what you did there. I can work out each of the bytes as a hex (0xF3 etc) but dont know how you got from 4 of those to the code U+F204B. Any chance you can help explain how to do that in visual basic and even where I can find info on how the Unicode points relate to the hexs to help educate me

Comment: "*However, I'm not sure how I can get to the code U+F204B from the byte array in visual basic*" - have you read the [UTF-8 spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629) yet? Do you know how to work with individual bits of a byte, using bit masks and bit shifts? `0xF3 0xB2 0x81 0x8B` is `11110011 10110010 10000001 10001011` in binary notation. Mask off the UTF-8 pattern bits gets you`xxxxx011 xx110010 xx000001 xx001011` for the codepoint bits (`00001111 00100000 01001011`), which is `0xF204B` in hex.

Comment: Otherwise, just import the Win32 [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) function and let it do the work for you using `CP_UTF8` as the codepage. I'm sure you can find an example if you search around.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your help so far, I confess I am self taught and all my projects are personal, so I apologise if I seem a little obtuse in some regards, but sometimes more of the technical stuff goes over my head.
I've been looking into the MultiByteToWideChar(), and whilst there is very little in the way of VB examples I seem to have gotten the impression that I would be better off using WideCharToMultiByte() and passing the original Html.innertext. Am I correct that this will return a code such as 0xF204B?
I am also having trouble understanding all the parameters that I need to pass

Comment: @SimonGreen `WideCharToMultiByte()` is for converting UTF-16 text into encoded bytes. `MultiByteToWideChar()` is for converting encoded bytes into UTF-16 text

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for your help, I found a way to do what I needed, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Whilst I wasn't able to fully achieve the goal of identifying the utf8 code of any character I did manage to find a way to identify the characters for my use case.

As it turned out, in my case there are around 30 characters and they appear more or less sequentially in the UTF8 codepage. Then the subject was to understand how the UTF8 code is formed, and user @RemyLebeau helped point me in the right direction. This video was very helpful for that: https://youtu.be/MijmeoH9LT4
My own summation is as follows:
1st byte: remove the first n+1 bits where n = the total number of bytes found
2nd - nth byte: remove the first two bits
the result should be combined starting from the rightmost bit and moving left, any spaces left to make a multiple of 8 should be filled with 0s.
so as in my example with 4 bytes:
243, 178, 129, 139
11110011, 10110010, 10000001, 10001011
*11110*-**011**, *10*-**110010**, *10*-**000001**, *10*-**001011**
000(011)(11, 0010)(0000, 01)(001011)
00001111, 00100000, 01001011
F, 20, 4B

now the code I used to help identify which character I was finding:

```
Dim utf8Encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(True)
Dim encodedString() As Byte
encodedString = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(HTML_Element.innerText)
Select Case encodedstring(3)
    Case 147
    Case 155
End Select
```

In my particular case I was able to use a hashtable to relate the value of the 4th byte to a separate value that I needed.
Is this a good solution? no, it only works in specific cases and being able to simply obtain the UTF8 code would create a solution that is more effective and elegant for all use cases. But as this is a project for personal use only, and through a combination of lack of personal understanding and lack of people willing to help me understand, this solution works for me and so I figured I would include it in case anybody finds themselves in a similar situation where the above shortcut might help.